# Почему не работает bluetooth на linux mint?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, grub, linux-mint, gnu

Установил linux mint. Bluetooth не работал, решил загуглить. Люди говорят надо установить blueman, но с ним то же не работает. Может кто нибудь помочь настроить bloetooth?
Вот что у меня установлено.[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:216c Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05c8:036e Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0cf3:9271 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

 $ lsmod | grep bluetooth
bluetooth             446409  22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
6lowpan_iphc           18702  1 bluetooth
 $ dmesg | grep -i  bluetooth
[    9.887714] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.19
[    9.887756] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    9.887764] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    9.887766] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    9.887776] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   10.133047] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[   10.133050] bluetooth hci0: Falling back to user helper
[   10.133680] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: patch brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216c.hcd not found
[   12.140246] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1003 tx timeout
[   15.851155] init: bluetooth-touch main process (876) terminated with status 127
[   16.843610] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   16.843620] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   16.843625] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   16.951108] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   16.951112] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   16.951120] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   20.230734] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1003 tx timeout
```

Comment: Точную модель ноута (на пузе указано) в студию!

Comment: @kff HP- Pavilion 15 p163nr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этом ноутбуке стоит чип Broadcom 43142 (Wi-Fi Direct™ & Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Chip for PCs & Notebooks). Попробуйте качнуть вот это: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/HfLy/Zh6cNZ4W5. А затем выполните

```
sudo cp BCM43142A0-0a5c-216c.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216c.hcd
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```

Может, заработает. А может, и нет... Мне не проверить, в зоне досягаемости даже приблизительно похожего чипа нет.

Comment: Спасибо большое, заработало!

Comment: После перезагрузки вообще не поределяет драйвер. Может что то с разрешениями не так?

Comment: Да, надо просто разрешения поменять, и всё работатьь будет после перезагрузки